# Visual Basic for Applications Excel compile error: Value Not Defined

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, compiler-errors

I am having an issue with a spreadsheet that has been working previously. When I click the "Add Sample" button (See image below) I get the Compile Error: Value Not Defined. In the Debugger it is shows it is occurring in `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` and looks like the hang-up is on `Date From`. Unfortunately this is not a spreadsheet I created. and not something I'm exceptionally familiar with. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim icol

    Tests.Clear

    ' if any additional tests have been added to this form, take note
    For icol = 11 To 29
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(9, icol) <> "" Then
            TestName = ActiveSheet.Cells(9, icol)
            AddTest_Click
        End If
    Next icol

    TestName = ""

    LookupType.Clear
    LookupType.AddItem "Composite"
    LookupType.AddItem "Sample"
    LookupType = "Composite"

    DateFrom = Now - 14
    DateTo = Now

    Select Case ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 25)
        Case "Fond du Lac"
            Site.Text = "FD"
        Case "Mountain Lake"
            Site.Text = "ML"
        Case "Norfolk"
            Site.Text = "NE"
        Case "Wautoma"
            Site.Text = "WT"
        Case "Visalia"
            Site.Text = "VS"
        Case Else
            Site.Text = ""
    End Select


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add `Dim DateFrom As Date` just before where you get an error. You need to declare all your variables.

Comment: Add `Dim DateFrom as Double` before that line.

Comment: add `Dim DateFrom as Date`.  Its also best practice to add `Option Explicit` to the top of every module; it will save you many headaches in the future.

Comment: Why double, @ScottCraner?

Comment: That is what a date is to Excel.  It is what I use.

Comment: But then you lose the perks from having a date variable, right?

Comment: @Damian what perks, Again Excel saves dates as doubles,  Yes one would explicitly need to set the format when assigning to a cell, but we do that anyway and not let excel default to an output.

Comment: Adding `Dim DateFrom as Double` as well as for DateTo did the trick, thank you all!!

Comment: Be explicit in the sheet you reference; don't use `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: While the `Date` keyword can be used for variable declarations, the keyword is "overloaded" to the point that it is also the name of an _application variable_ that contains the date value. When time is not important, I prefer to use `Date` instead of `Now` in VBA calculations: `DateFrom = Date - 14` for example. Just thought I'd throw that out there.